# Can the halting prοblem be sοlved for certain finite functions?

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem

It is my understanding that for a sufficiently simple function, let's say

```
function(boolean input){
    while(input){
    }
}
```

it is possible to tell if it will halt for any possible input.

It is easy to see that the above function will terminate for `false` and not terminate for `true. It's only impossible to solve the halting problem for an arbitrary function`f`, as of course you can evaluate`haltingFinder(haltingFinder)` and essentially create a paradox.

Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: I case anyone is wondering about the 0 in the word problem, I was defeating the system designed to prevent homework questions.

Comment: This is a good question, but maybe for cstheory.SE. They should probably accept the word "problem" in the title

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better off in http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Mr.Negi You might be interested in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991323/hitting-a-point-on-an-expanding-grid) (Sorry for an irrelevant comment, I will delete it after some time)

Comment: I know saying thanks is against the rules and irrelevant to this problem, but I feel it is strictly necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course you are right. Take a funtion that does not even have a loop: it will always halt. For entire classes like the regular and context-free languages the halting problem is trivial: the corresponding machines (finite automata, pushdown-automata without epsilon moves) can only make a number of steps equal to the input word's length and thus will always halt. Though, of course, you can design non-halting computations for simple funtions, e.g. a Turing Machine with useless loops for a regular language.